# Are there discussion sites online for university level mathematics?

Tags: calculus, probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, self-learning

I have been trying to learn maths on my own for a while, I've realised most of the problems that stump me would be solved in 5 seconds, if I had a mentor. Of course, learning on your own teaches you problem solving, but too often I'm banging my head against the wall on something I was not ready for. Teaching yourself math is like fumbling around in the dark. It is clear that my highschool math curriculum has not prepared me for the advanced math I am trying to learn. Most books I've come across seem to assume a classroom setting, there are solutions missing, the language too terse.

I know StackExchange is a question and answer site, not for discussions. So where could a math autodidact go online to discuss math? Preferably with others who are also self learning higher level mathematics or those who are knowledgeable about mathematics and can act as mentor. I don't mind paying a subscription, if there is such a service.

Comment: I'm an autodidact myself and I found that the Art of Problem Solving has a forum for college level math which was very useful. You can find it here. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7_college_math

Comment: See also http://reddit.com/r/learnmath, http://reddit.com/r/askmath, http://reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework, http://reddit.com/r/math